# Testing typescript with Jasmine in vs 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, jasmine, chutzpah

I am trying to test typescript in vs2013 using Jasmine and Chutzpaah, when I right click on  my `test.ts` file which has below content and select `Run JS Tests`, it keeps showing testing is pending in the test explorer.
Am I doing correct or is there another way to test this?

```
    /// <reference path="../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />

/// <reference path="person.ts" />


describe("Person FullName", () => {

    var person: Person;

    beforeEach(() => {

        person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Joe");
        person.setLastName("Smith");
    });

    it("should concatenate first and last names", () => {
        expect(person.getFullName()).toBe("Joe, Smith");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give definitive answer to you question without knowing configuration of your project and what is in your chutzpah.json configuration. It could be difficult setup chutzpah at first but the following steps could help diagnose problems:

1. Enable tracing in VS->Tools->Options->Chutzpah Setting. This will write extensive log to C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\chutzpah.log
2. Try to run tests in browser (Open in browser context menu option) with F12 tools on.
3. See what's in Output. There is two relevant output sources: Tests and Test
4. Use [chutzpah settings](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File). These is log you can tweak using it.